# Getting memory leaks in Glib/GDBus code?

Tags: garbage-collection, glib

I'm using GDBus (via Glib) and I have code like:

```
  method_call_message = g_dbus_message_new_method_call(owner,
                                                       OBJECT_PATH,
                                                       INTERFACE_NAME,
                                                       "get_snmpv2_mib");

  GVariant *gv = g_variant_new("(sissi)", ip, port, mib, variable, instance);

  g_dbus_message_set_body(method_call_message, gv);
```

I assume *method_call_message* is now a container for *gv*.

Before exiting I call:

```
 g_object_unref(method_call_message);
```

I assume this will then schedule BOTH *method_call_message* and *gv* for GC?

When is GC done?

I appear to be leaking some 4 bytes at a time as I watch the **top** updates on VIRT memory.

I have commented out pieces of code till I localized it (the leak) to my GDBus calls.

Comment: GLib is not garbage collected it uses reference counting. Yes the variant is floating and set_body() assumes ownership over it.

Comment: I checked and the ref-counts for both method_call_message and gv are ZERO. After calling g_object_unref(method_call_message);

So what do I need to do to reclaim the storage/memory? Call a routine? If so, what routine? If not, what?

Answer (score 1):

Using some Valgrind magic:

```
libtool exec valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --log-file=w <executable + args>
```

I was able to winnow out the memory management obfuscation and get to a call-stack that showed the problem. The Valgrind output indicated that all my memory losses were associated with calls to ***g_variant_get(...)***:

```
at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E503B6: g_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E6860D: g_strdup (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E7FD01: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E7FA61: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E80348: g_variant_get_va (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E80585: g_variant_get (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x4C30555: server_gvariant (in /usr/lib64/libdrsnvc.so)
==20088==    by 0x40257B: NVCtimerCB(void*) (main.cc:73)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E48C3A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E48519: g_main_context_dispatch (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==20088==    by 0x3F21E4A5A7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
```

Obviously the call to ***g_variant_get(...)*** begats a call to ***g_strdup(...)*** (if your ***format_string*** includes an 's' for string). So, in my case, the code is:

```
g_variant_get(response, "(isi)", &od.stat, &od.msg, &od.i);
gchar *tmp = od.msg;
od.msg = strncpy(msg, od.msg, strlen(od.msg)); /* copy string */
g_free(tmp); /* free g_strdup allocated space */
```

And a call to ***g_free(...)*** frees the allocated storage.

Now I get:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
==6472==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6472==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6472==      possibly lost: 9,841 bytes in 148 blocks
==6472==    still reachable: 106,376 bytes in 986 blocks
==6472==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```