# Memory Management in Glib

Tags: memory-management, glib

How is storage/memory reclaimed in Glib? I've called g_object_unref() and the ref-counts are zero but I'm not sure any storage is ever reclaimed.

Do I need to call a routine? If so, which routine. If not, what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting memory leaks in Glib/GDBus code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987043/getting-memory-leaks-in-glib-gdbus-code)

Answer (score 0):

Much of the memory allocation in GLib is done using the slice allocator, which has better performance when allocating lots of identical-sized blocks of memory, as happens a lot in GLib-using code.

You won't see memory usage jump up and down with the slice allocator in the same way that you would when using traditional malloc. The slice allocator often keeps memory in use for a while in order to reallocate it to other blocks.

If you want to force the slice allocator to behave like malloc, use the environment variable `G_SLICE=always-malloc`. That's not recommended for  production, but it is the recommended way to use valgrind on GLib programs.